# How do I take an array of row locations and an array of column locations and make a new array of the combined points?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to take a 1x3 matrix of 'row' values, where a = ([1],[3],[5]) and a 3x1 matrix of column values, b = ([1,4,7]) , and create a 3x3 matrix of (row, column) values so that the final matrix would look like

([(1,1) (1,4) (1,7)],

[(3,1) (3,4) (3,7)],

[(5,1) (5,4) (5,7)])

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,4,7]).reshape((3,1))
b = np.array([1,3,5]).reshape((1,3))
```

Comment: That's not a matrix, but looks like many tuples. What exactly must be the output : array/list of tuples/ etc.? Look into `numpy.meshgrid`.

Comment: Apologies, was going for a visual look to my question. Output is a 3x3 array where each i,j = tuple given by the row and column vector. I'm trying to take a row vector and a column vector and create an array of 'reference locations' that I can then use to find specific locations in a final vector (out of the scope of the question here).

Comment: `np.array(list(itertools.product(b,a)), dtype=np.dtype('int,int')).T.reshape(3,3)` if you just supply a and b as the lists instead of reshaped arrays. Probably using a list comprehension is easier though..